# Is it better to require a file once and transfer it with a function parameter or to require it each time in the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Which situation is the most efficiency ?⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣⁣
`file1.js`

```js
// Situation 1
const lang = require(`path/to/file/${value}`);
file2.run({ lang });
// Situation 2
const lang = value;
file2.run({ lang });
```

`file2.js`

```js
// Situation 1
exports.run = runArgs => {
    const { lang } = runArgs;
    // lang has already the wanted value.
};
// Situation 2
exports.run = runArgs => {
    const { lang } = runArgs;
    const language = require(`path/to/file/${lang}`);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a file got "required" once, Node caches it, all the other "requires" (from other files) will use the same cached value, so you should keep it simple and require the module from all the files that need it.

You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) and [here](https://bambielli.com/til/2017-04-30-node-require-cache/#:%7E:text=Per%20the%20node%20documentation%2C%20modules,loaded%20by%20the%20first%20require.)